# Status bar activity indicator not displaying on separate .xib file note included in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I am having a problem displaying the activity indicator in a view that is not part of my storyboard. It is a .xib file that is included in the project but the same code that I use to display the activity indicator in the storyboard views (which works with out a problem) is **not** working on that extra .xib file. The code that I am using to show the activity indicator is below:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

}
```

As I said before, it works on all the views that are in my storyboard but not on the extra .xib view. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

use it, may be helpful for you :)

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {    

        UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

        [self.ActiveIndicatorName startAnimating];
    }
```